# How to get more detailed information when mamba encounters problem while solving environment?

Tags: python, conda, virtual-environment, mamba

When installing trying to install `snakemake` together with `Python v3.11` in a `mamba` (conda) environment, `mamba` gives me the following error:

```
$ mamba create -n py311-snakemake python=3.11 snakemake  
Encountered problems while solving:
  - package snakemake-7.3.1-hdfd78af_1 requires snakemake-minimal 7.3.1.*, 
    but none of the providers can be installed
```

I would like to know how I can investigate which package exactly is not (yet) compatible with Python 3.11 without having to manually traverse the dependency graph.

If I manually install one problematic dependency after another, I can find the solution, but I'm wondering whether there's a simpler way. Surely there exists a better solution, more automatic and convenient, than manually doing this.

`mamba` docs recommend running it in triple verbose mode `-vvv` but that's just very overwhelming (20k lines output) and doesn't appear like a better solution than manual traversing to me.

How do others do this? Is this just not yet implemented or am I missing a trick?

This is the manual way through which I find that `datrie` is the package that doesn't support 3.11 yet:

```
$ mamba create -n py311-snakemake python=3.11 snakemake-minimal
...
Encountered problems while solving:
  - package snakemake-minimal-5.10.0-py_0 requires datrie,
    but none of the providers can be installed

$ mamba create -n py311-snakemake python=3.11 datrie
...
Encountered problems while solving:
  - package datrie-0.7.1-py36h1de35cc_0 requires python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0,
    but none of the providers can be installed
```

However even like that, it would be nice to be told that `datrie` works with the next most recent Python version 3.10 - not sure why it shows me a datrie v0.7.1 that only works with Python 3.6, and not datrie v0.8.2 that works with Python 3.10 at least.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some channels:

```
mamba create -c conda-forge -c bioconda -n py311-snakemake python=3.11 snakemake
```

If you don't add channels, mamba will use the defaults channel, which does not contain Snakemake. The error messages can sometimes be a little hard to read and oftentimes will not give you a clear hint how to proceed. But as a minimum, add channels. Hope it helps.